# List all files within a folder (prefix) inside an AWS S3 Bucket using the AWS PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk, buckets

I'm having some troubles listing all the files within certain prefix of an AWS S3 Bucket.

I have searched and search, but only seem to be able to find the same information:

```
try {
$objects = $s3Client->getIterator('ListObjects', array(
    'Bucket' => 'BUCKETNAME',
    'Prefix' => '/uploads/content/document/'
));
    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo $object['Key'] . "\n";
    }
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```

This will give back a fair bit of information if I `print_r($objects)` however, nothing is echo'd out in the loop, and no matter what I try, I can't seem to get it to list any files.

I actually have another 6 folders I want to retrieve a list of files from, however, obviously need to get it working with just `document` for now.

I have tried removing the final / on the prefix, as well as using '`listObjects`':

```
$s3Client->getIterator('listObjects' ...
```

and even with trying a different method of just `ListObjects` or `ListObjectsV2` (found this information).  The first one works but again doesn't list any files, and the second method isn't found.

```
$s3Client->ListObjects(array( ...
$s3Client->ListObjectsV2(array( ...
```

No doubt i'm missing something.  All I want to achieve is the list of all files names within each of the folders/prefixes, so I can list these and use some clever jQuery to add them into a document when selected in our CMS, sure there should be more information on this somewhere!!!

Any help would be much appreciated.

`print_r($objects)` returns: http://pastebin.com/YwWLLsSK

Comment: Try removing starting `/` character. Usually prefixes do not start with the delimiter: `'Prefix' => 'uploads/content/document/'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing most important key to set which is

like this
                // 'ap-southeast-1' for asian region

```
            'region'  => 'ap-southeast-1',
```